# PHP read folder only works with absolute path

Tags: php, wordpress, image, getfiles

I have a function that reads out a folder containing images.
The problem is that it only works if the path to the folder is absolute.

If I change it to a dynamic path it throws me an error.

Here is the function:

```
<?php 
function getPathsByKind($path,$ext,$err_type = false)
{
    # Assign the error type, default is fatal error
    if($err_type === false)
        $err_type   =   E_USER_ERROR;
    # Check if the path is valid
    if(!is_dir($path)) {
        # Throw fatal error if folder doesn't exist
        trigger_error('Folder does not exist. No file paths can be returned.',$err_type);
        # Return false incase user error is just notice...
        return false;
    }
    # Set a storage array
    $file   =   array();
    # Get path list of files
    $it     =   new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path,RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS)
    );
    # Loop and assign paths
    foreach($it as $filename => $val) {
        if(strtolower(pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == strtolower($ext)) {
            $file[] =   $filename;
        }
    }
    # Return the path list
    return $file;
}
?>
```

and here is how I fetch it:

```
<?php 
# Assign directory path
//$directory = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/domainname/wp-content/themes/themename/images/logos/'; 
// THIS PART ABOVE IS THE ABSOLUTE PATH AND IS WORKING.

$directory = get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/images/logos/';


$files = getPathsByKind($directory,'svg');
if(!empty($files)) {
    for($i=0; $i < 32; $i++){
        echo '<img src="'.$files[$i].'">';
    }
}
?>
```

How can I make it work with a relative path?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: My bad. See updates question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna answer your question with a question: why should it work with a relative path?

The most likely reason why it doesn't work with a relative path is, the current working directory is not what you think it is. You can check it with `getcwd()` function.

This is also the biggest problem with relative paths: you can **NEVER** rely on them. Current working directory can be set from outside the script with `chdir()` any time for any reason.

Whenever you work with files on your server, **ALWAYS** use absolute paths. If you want to resolve a path relative to the script file, **ALWAYS** use `__DIR__` or `dirname()`.

In your case, the problem with your code is that your `getPathsByKind` function returns absolute paths to the images, which are useless for anyone except localhost. What you can do is make `getPathsByKind` return just file names instead of full paths. Replace line

```
$file[] =   $filename;
```

with

```
$file[] = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
```

then, prepend the path in `img` tag:

```
for($i=0; $i < 32; $i++){
    echo '<img src="/images/logos/or/whatever/'.$files[$i].'">';
}
```

Comment: Okay makes sense. But how do you propose I's solve this? I mean I want to load the path into a `<img src` value. but this can't be done with a absolute path.

Comment: In your `getPathsByKind` function, replace line `$file[] = $filename;` with something that returns paths relative to your images directory. You don't need to pass relative paths _to_ the function in order to get relative paths _from_ the function.

Comment: Sorry man I'm a little over my head here. I'll do some Googling to understand this a little better!

Comment: Edited my answer to illustrate the solution better.

Comment: Oh man. I see what you mean. I constantly thought the image names were loaded and that's why needed to add a directory path. So now the image names are loaded and I can use a absolute path.  Thank you for explaining!